# Помогите сделать autolink?

Tags: javascript

Помогите сделать autolink js?
Задача сделать гиперссылки в тексте автоматически кликабельными как в Google Docs, iCloud Pages и MS Word. 
Наподобии такого [image: img]

Имеется `<div id="text" class="status" onclick="this.contentEditable=true;" contenteditable="true"></div>`

и скрипт:

```
     `function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text,re) {
     return text.replace(re, function(match, lParens, url) {
     var rParens = '';
     lParens = lParens || '';
     var lParenCounter = /\(/g;
     while (lParenCounter.exec(lParens)) {
        var m;
        if (m = /(.*)(\.\).*)/.exec(url) ||
                /(.*)(\).*)/.exec(url)) {
            url = m[1];
            rParens = m[2] + rParens;
        }
     }
    return lParens + "<a onclick=window.open("+url+"); href='" + url + "'>" 
    + url + "</a>" + rParens;
    });
    }
    var text = document.getElementById('text');
    var re = /(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/;
    if (text.innerHTML.match(re)) {
        text.onkeydown =(function() {
    alert(replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text.innerHTML,re));
    text.onmouseover = (function() {
        this.contentEditable = false;
        this.innerHTML = replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(this.innerHTML,re);
    });
    });
    }`
```

Не могу понять почему не работает. подскажите как можно сделать подобное? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Несколько примеров.
Скрипты лежат [здесь](https://pastebin.com/qSmfKRC2) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233265/contenteditable-set-caret-at-the-end-of-the-text-cross-browser/4238971#4238971).
Ссылки почему то тут не открываются - [здесь](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPO5ZNHKCY35) все работает.

```js
var Q;
Q = {};
Q.a = '';
Q.b = '';
Q.url = '';
Q.c = '';
Q.i = 0; // счетчик символов

function Go(elem) {
  var text = elem.innerText; // текст из дива в переменную
  var m = text.length; // количество символов из дива в переменную
  if (m > Q.i) { // если количество символов больше чем счетчик (дописали символ)
    Q.c += text[text.length - 1]; // к переменнoй Q.c добавляем последний символ 
    elem.innerHTML = findAndReplaceLink(Q.c); // вводим в див текст с сылками
    placeCaretAtEnd(elem); // кидаем курсор в конец текста в диве
    Q.i++; // счетчик символов +1
  } else { // иначе - если нажали на клаве Baskspace (удалили символ)
    Q.c = text; // к переменнoй Q.c добавляем весь текст из дива
    elem.innerHTML = findAndReplaceLink(Q.c); // вводим в див текст с сылками
    placeCaretAtEnd(elem); // кидаем курсор в конец текста в диве
    Q.i--; // счетчик символов -1
  }
};

function StartUrl() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('url');
  elem.href = Q.url;
  elem.click();
};

//------------------- Скрипт перекидывает курсор в конец текста в DIVе ---------
//--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233265/contenteditable-set-caret-at-the-end-of-the-text-cross-browser/4238971#4238971
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
  el.focus();
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" &&
    typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    range.collapse(false);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
    var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    textRange.moveToElementText(el);
    textRange.collapse(false);
    textRange.select();
  }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------findAndReplaceLink-------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function findAndReplaceLink(inputText) {
  function indexOf(arr, value, from) {
    for (var i = from || 0, l = (arr || []).length; i < l; i++) {
      if (arr[i] == value) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }

  function clean(str) {
    return str ? str.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&#039;') : '';
  }

  function replaceEntities(str) {
    return se('<textarea>' + ((str || '').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;')) + '</textarea>').value;
  }

  function se(html) {
    return ce('div', {
      innerHTML: html
    }).firstChild;
  }

  function ce(tagName, attr, style) {
    var el = document.createElement(tagName);
    if (attr) extend(el, attr);
    if (style) setStyle(el, style);
    return el;
  }

  function setStyle(elem, name, value) {
    elem = ge(elem);
    if (!elem) return;
    if (typeof name == 'object') return each(name, function(k, v) {
      setStyle(elem, k, v);
    });
    if (name == 'opacity') {
      if (browser.msie) {
        if ((value + '').length) {
          if (value !== 1) {
            elem.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value * 100 + ')';
          } else {
            elem.style.filter = '';
          }
        } else {
          elem.style.cssText = elem.style.cssText.replace(/filter\s*:[^;]*/gi, '');
        }
        elem.style.zoom = 1;
      };
      elem.style.opacity = value;
    } else {
      try {
        var isN = typeof(value) == 'number';
        if (isN && (/height|width/i).test(name)) value = Math.abs(value);
        elem.style[name] = isN && !(/z-?index|font-?weight|opacity|zoom|line-?height/i).test(name) ? value + 'px' : value;
      } catch (e) {
        debugLog('setStyle error: ', [name, value], e);
      }
    }
  }

  function extend() {
    var a = arguments,
      target = a[0] || {},
      i = 1,
      l = a.length,
      deep = false,
      options;

    if (typeof target === 'boolean') {
      deep = target;
      target = a[1] || {};
      i = 2;
    }

    if (typeof target !== 'object' && !isFunction(target)) target = {};

    for (; i < l; ++i) {
      if ((options = a[i]) != null) {
        for (var name in options) {
          var src = target[name],
            copy = options[name];

          if (target === copy) continue;

          if (deep && copy && typeof copy === 'object' && !copy.nodeType) {
            target[name] = extend(deep, src || (copy.length != null ? [] : {}), copy);
          } else if (copy !== undefined) {
            target[name] = copy;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return target;
  }

  var replacedText = (inputText || '').replace(/(^|[^A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яёЁ\-\_])(https?:\/\/)?((?:[A-Za-z\$0-9А-Яа-яёЁ](?:[A-Za-z\$0-9\-\_А-Яа-яёЁ]*[A-Za-z\$0-9А-Яа-яёЁ])?\.){1,5}[A-Za-z\$рфуконлайнстРФУКОНЛАЙНСТ\-\d]{2,22}(?::\d{2,5})?)((?:\/(?:(?:\&amp;|\&#33;|,[_%]|[A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яёЁ\-\_#%?+\/\$.~=;:]+|\[[A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яёЁ\-\_#%?+\/\$.,~=;:]*\]|\([A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яёЁ\-\_#%?+\/\$.,~=;:]*\))*(?:,[_%]|[A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яёЁ\-\_#%?+\/\$.~=;:]*[A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яёЁ\_#%?+\/\$~=]|\[[A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яёЁ\-\_#%?+\/\$.,~=;:]*\]|\([A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яёЁ\-\_#%?+\/\$.,~=;:]*\)))?)?)/ig,
    function() { // copied to notifier.js:3401
      var matches = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments),
        prefix = matches[1] || '',
        protocol = matches[2] || 'http://',
        domain = matches[3] || '',
        url = domain + (matches[4] || ''),
        full = (matches[2] || '') + matches[3] + matches[4];

      if (domain.indexOf('.') == -1 || domain.indexOf('..') != -1) return matches[0];
      var topDomain = domain.split('.').pop();
      if (topDomain.length > 6 || indexOf('info,name,aero,arpa,coop,museum,mobi,travel,xxx,asia,biz,com,net,org,gov,mil,edu,int,tel,ac,ad,ae,af,ag,ai,al,am,an,ao,aq,ar,as,at,au,aw,ax,az,ba,bb,bd,be,bf,bg,bh,bi,bj,bm,bn,bo,br,bs,bt,bv,bw,by,bz,ca,cc,cd,cf,cg,ch,ci,ck,cl,cm,cn,co,cr,cu,cv,cx,cy,cz,de,dj,dk,dm,do,dz,ec,ee,eg,eh,er,es,et,eu,fi,fj,fk,fm,fo,fr,ga,gd,ge,gf,gg,gh,gi,gl,gm,gn,gp,gq,gr,gs,gt,gu,gw,gy,hk,hm,hn,hr,ht,hu,id,ie,il,im,in,io,iq,ir,is,it,je,jm,jo,jp,ke,kg,kh,ki,km,kn,kp,kr,kw,ky,kz,la,lb,lc,li,lk,lr,ls,lt,lu,lv,ly,ma,mc,md,me,mg,mh,mk,ml,mm,mn,mo,mp,mq,mr,ms,mt,mu,mv,mw,mx,my,mz,na,nc,ne,nf,ng,ni,nl,no,np,nr,nu,nz,om,pa,pe,pf,pg,ph,pk,pl,pm,pn,pr,ps,pt,pw,py,qa,re,ro,ru,rs,rw,sa,sb,sc,sd,se,sg,sh,si,sj,sk,sl,sm,sn,so,sr,ss,st,su,sv,sx,sy,sz,tc,td,tf,tg,th,tj,tk,tl,tm,tn,to,tp,tr,tt,tv,tw,tz,ua,ug,uk,um,us,uy,uz,va,vc,ve,vg,vi,vn,vu,wf,ws,ye,yt,yu,za,zm,zw,рф,укр,сайт,онлайн,срб,cat,pro,local'.split(','), topDomain) == -1) {
        if (!/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(topDomain) || !matches[2]) {
          return matches[0];
        }
      }

      if (matches[0].indexOf('@') != -1) {
        return matches[0];
      }
      try {
        full = decodeURIComponent(full);
      } catch (e) {}

      if (full.length > 55) {
        full = full.substr(0, 53) + '..';
      }
      full = clean(full).replace(/&amp;/g, '&');

      url = replaceEntities(url).replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9#%;_\-.\/?&=\[\]])/g, encodeURIComponent);
      var tryUrl = url,
        hashPos = url.indexOf('#/');
      if (hashPos >= 0) {
        tryUrl = url.substr(hashPos + 1);
      } else {
        hashPos = url.indexOf('#!');
        if (hashPos >= 0) {
          tryUrl = '/' + url.substr(hashPos + 2).replace(/^\//, '');
        }
      }
      return prefix + '<a onclick="StartUrl();" onmouseover="Q.url=this.href;" href="' + (protocol + url).replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;') + '" target="_blank">' + full + '</a>';
    });

  return replacedText;
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}

body,
input,
span {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 0px;
}

input,
span,
div {
  outline: 0;
  outline-offset: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="ok" style="border-color: green;" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="if (window.event.keyCode == 13 ) return false;else Go(this);" onclick="if (this.innerHTML == 'Type your post') this.innerHTML = '';">Type your post</div>
<br>
<textarea onclick="this.value = ''" onkeyup="document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = findAndReplaceLink(this.value)">Текст</textarea><br><br>

<div id="b">&nbsp;</div><br>

<div>
  <span id="c" onclick="this.innerHTML = '';document.getElementById('cc').focus()">Текст</span>
  <input id="cc" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="Q.a += findAndReplaceLink(this.value);document.getElementById('c').innerHTML = findAndReplaceLink(Q.a);this.value = '';this.style.marginLeft ='-5px'" onclick="document.getElementById('c').click()"></div>
<br>
<div>
  <span id="d" onclick="this.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';document.getElementById('dd').innerHTML = '';var elem = document.getElementById('dd');elem.focus();elem.style.marginLeft ='-8px';">Текст</span>
  <span id="dd" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="Q.b += findAndReplaceLink(this.innerHTML);document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = findAndReplaceLink(Q.b);this.innerHTML = '';this.style.marginLeft ='-4px'"></span>&nbsp;</div>

<a style="display:none;" id="url" href="" target="_blank">OOO</a>
```

Comment: Это я тоже видел, а как мне отправить ссылку в тот же div в котором я пишу? как на картинке.

Comment: Добавил нужный div и отключил `ENTER`.

Comment: Спасибо, еще нужна почта `@gmail.com` или `@mail.ru`, подскажите куда добавить? и можно вернуть `Enter`? я убрал `window.event.keyCode` но он все равно пишет в этом divе

Comment: Добавил почту - [ссылка](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPPV9NCSAHWM). Подумаю как убрать `Enter`

Comment: И еще можно как-то продолжить редактировать текст на любой месте, перед ссылкой, внутри текста? Когда я хочу вставить текст перед содержимым, перебрасывает курсор на конец divа.

Comment: А как на счет готового [решения](https://jsfiddle.net/froala/5bcttehk/)?  Брал [здесь](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples).

Comment: Классно, мне нужно чтобы ссылка была кликабельной, без дополнительного клика по нему, как у iCloud Pages. Нужно сделать custom-ную ссылку. Или можно как-то подогнать этот редактор, чтобы можно было просто редактировать текст где-угодно?

Comment: А такой вариант [подойдет](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPSM14M18W2R). Время изменения текста (через 6 секунд, от последнего нажатия клавиши).

Comment: Да, вполне подойдет, спасибо. Но как сделать без таймера, чтобы он все-таки через onkeypress срабатывал, т.е. сразу видел что я пишу ссылку? Я могу писать ссылку больше чем 6 с и он сразу сделает ей ссылкой но еще и недописанной, а если поставить больше секунд то долго ждать, когда ссылка будет доступной.

Comment: Еще [вариант](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPT1TXAJ7163). Писать текст можно как хочешь долго, форматирование текста происходит через `6` секунд после `последнего нажатия клавиши`. Работает `ENTER`. Добавил кнопку пред-просмотр. На `onkeypress` не получается `пока` повесить, слетает каретка. Нужно как то вычислять положение каретки, записывать туда символ, и уже после форматирования текста возвращать каретку после записанного символа :).

Comment: Задал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/806136/244950) по теме каретки.

Comment: Для div [подобная](https://jsfiddle.net/say5vvc6/) функция setCaretPosition не работает, для divа нужно, наверно, что-то другое.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один момент, есть код сохраняющий данные в БД через ajax

```
PHP
<pre>

$sel_client = $db->query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE id_client='2'");
$data_cl = $sel_client->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
$form_company = $data_cl['form_company'];

if(isset($_POST["content"])) {
    $fc = $_POST["content"];
    $up_sc2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE client SET form_company=:form_company 
    WHERE 
    id_client='2'");
    $keys2 = ['form_company' => $fc];
    $up_sc2->execute($keys2);
}
</pre>
JS
<pre>
function savedata(elementidsave,contentsave) {
    $.ajax({    url: 'test6.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {content: contentsave,
                      id:elementidsave},                
                success:function (data) {
                }});
   } 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[contenteditable="true"]').keyup(function (e) {
      var text = document.getElementById('text');
        var contentold={};
         elementid=this.id;
         contentold[elementid]=$(this).html();

         //показываем кнопку "сохранить"
        var elementidsave=this.id;
           var contentsave = $(this).html();
                 savedata(elementidsave,contentsave);
});
  });
</pre>
```

Я пишу текст и он сразу сохраняется в БД.
Но, когда я перезагружая страницу, все удаляется. Может знаешь как исправить?