# Как заставить каретку возвращаться на нужную позицию?

Tags: javascript

Есть [такой](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPT2RUQZBJAS) пример.

Как сделать так, чтобы после запуска скрипта и форматирования текста в редактируемом `DIVe` через `onkeypress`?

1. Символы вводились на нужную позицию.
2. Каретка возвращалась на нужную позицию.

Спасибо заранее